# Custom MultiIterator with type filter

Tags: java, performance, iterator

I'll start with giving a bit of background as there are many classes involved and I can't attach all of them because that would make this question wildly too long. For the curios they can be found at [my github repo](https://github.com/EmilyBjoerk/lsml).

I have an immutable structure called a `Chassis` which consists of 8 immutable `Component`s. Each `Component` is named by a `Location` such as `Location.LeftArm` or `Location.RightTorso`.

A `Loadout` is a particular configuration of `Item`s that are equipped on a `Chassis`. For each `Component` on the `Chassis`, the `Loadout` has a matching `ConfiguredComponent` that contains the `Item`s equipped on that component of the `Chassis`. In addition to this, each `Component` can have a number of fixed `Item`s and some `Items` are kind of fixed but can be toggled on and off (not my decision, that's the game rules). So the toggle state is a part of the `ConfiguredComponent` which is why `ConfiguredComponent` has a `getItemsFixed()` method which will return the truly fixed items + any items which have their toggle state set to enabled.

In many places in the code base I need to iterate over all items on the `Loadout` (fixed and removable). Even more frequently I'm only interested in certain types of items on the loadout. For example those that are a subclass of `Weapon` which is an `Item` or even those items that implement a particular interface not necessarily inheriting from `Item`. In other words I may want to filter on a class that is not descendant from `Item`. However all items on the loadout have `Item` as a base class.

To this end I decided upon letting `Loadout` have methods to return an `Iterable` of approriate type which I can use to iterate over `Items` of a particular type. Then I implement a form of MultiIterator that can iterate over all the `Item`s on the Loadout.

Relevant excerpt from `Loadout`:

```
public abstract class LoadoutBase<T extends ConfiguredComponentBase> {
   public Iterable<Item> items(){
      return new LoadoutIterable<Item>(this, null);
   }

   public <X> Iterable<X> items(Class<X> aClass){
      return new LoadoutIterable<X>(this, aClass);
   }
}
```

Implementation of glue class `LoadoutIterable`:

```
public class LoadoutIterable<T> implements Iterable<T>{
   private final LoadoutBase<?> loadout;
   private final Class<T> filter;

   public LoadoutIterable(LoadoutBase<?> aLoadout, Class<T> aFilter){
      loadout = aLoadout;
      filter = aFilter;
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<T> iterator(){
      return new LoadoutItemIterator<T>(loadout, filter);
   }
}
```

And finally the `Iterator` itself (remember, `T` might not extend `Item` at all but there might be some instance of a subclass of `Item` that implements `T`):

```
public class LoadoutItemIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
   private static enum IterationState{
      Fixed, Equipped
   }

   private final static Location[] LOCATION_ORDER;
   private List<Item>              items;
   private IterationState          state           = IterationState.Fixed;
   private int                     index           = 0;
   private final LoadoutBase<?>    loadout;
   private final Class<T>          filter;
   private Location                currentLocation = LOCATION_ORDER[0];

   static{
      LOCATION_ORDER = new Location[Location.values().length];
      for(Location location : Location.values()){
         LOCATION_ORDER[location.ordinal()] = location;
      }
   }

   LoadoutItemIterator(LoadoutBase<?> aLoadout, Class<T> aFilter){
      loadout = aLoadout;
      filter = aFilter;
      items = loadout.getComponent(currentLocation).getItemsFixed();
   }

   LoadoutItemIterator(LoadoutBase<?> aLoadout){
      this(aLoadout, null);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext(){
      return null != getNextNonFiltered();
   }

   @Override
   public T next(){
      T ans = getNextNonFiltered();
      index++;
      return ans;
   }

   @Override
   public void remove(){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private T getNextNonFiltered(){
      while( true ){
         if( index < items.size() ){
            Item item = items.get(index);
            if( filter == null || filter.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass()) ){
               return (T)item; // This cast is checked
            }
            index++;
         }
         else{
            index = 0;
            if( state == IterationState.Fixed ){
               state = IterationState.Equipped;
               items = loadout.getComponent(currentLocation).getItemsEquipped();
            }
            else{
               if( currentLocation.ordinal() == LOCATION_ORDER.length - 1 ){
                  return null; // End of items
               }
               currentLocation = LOCATION_ORDER[currentLocation.ordinal() + 1];
               state = IterationState.Fixed;
               items = loadout.getComponent(currentLocation).getItemsFixed();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
LoadoutBase<?> loadout = ...;
for(Weapon weapon : loadout.items(Weapon.class)){
   ...;
}
```

The code works as is and I have achieved my sought for syntax for iterating over specific types of items on the loadout. However there are a few things nagging me, most prominently the unchecked cast in `LoadoutItemIterator.getNextNonFiltered`.

I would like help with:

- How can I (if I can) get rid of the unchecked cast?
- Better naming?
- Performance of `LoadoutItemIterator`. I tried implementing using `Iterator`s to each sub list individually but that proved to be slower than this implementation. Without filtering this is about 20% faster than just slamming all the sublists into a new list and returning that.
- Other suggestions for design or solutions to the problem.

And I'm sorry for being unable to provide a runnable example, but I feel like that would be too much work for the reviewer. If you do wish to run the code you can check it out from the github repository at the top and run the gradle setup script to get the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need your `private static enum IterationState`? If it is simply used in a flag-like manner to toggle betweed `Fixed` and `Equipped` values, then may I suggest replacing it entirely by a `boolean` value instead?

**Going with my assumption above**, I can then think about using a method to standardize how I assign the `items` variable:

```
private void setItems() {
    // not sure Component is the same as yours or not, I'm just going by naming convention
    final Component component = loadout.getComponent(currentLocation);
    items = isItemsFixed ? component.getItemsFixed() : component.getItemsEquipped();
}
```

The start of `LoadoutItemIterator` will look something like this (incorporating [@maaartinus's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61394/27975) suggestion):

```
public class LoadoutItemIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final static Location[] LOCATION_ORDER = Location.values();
    // ...
    private boolean isItemsFixed = true;

    LoadoutItemIterator(LoadoutBase<?> aLoadout, Class<T> aFilter) {
        loadout = aLoadout;
        filter = aFilter;
        setItems();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The body of your `while(true)` loop can be changed *significantly too*:

```
// body of while-loop
if (index < items.size()) {
    Item item = items.get(index);
    if (filter == null || filter.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) {
        return (T) item; // This cast is checked
    }
    index++;
} else if (prepareNextItemsToLoad() && (currentLocation = currentLocation.next()) == null) {
    return null; // actually, do you want to throw NoSuchElementException? see below
} else {
    setItems();
}

// method implementation
private boolean prepareNextItemsToLoad() {
    index = 0;
    isItemsFixed = !isItemsFixed;
    return isItemsFixed;
}
```

I am employing a tiny shortcut/trick for the `else if` clause. You want to move to the next `Location` (again, using @maaartinus's suggestion for a `Location.next()`) when you have finished iterating through the *equipped* items for the `currentLocation`. Thus, `currentLocation.next()` is assigned to `currentLocation` when `!isItemsFixed`. It is compared with `null` to see whether the result of calling `next()` exhausts the `Location` values. If so, we `return null`, just like what you have. Otherwise, all we are left to do is to `setItems()`, since we have conveniently reset `index = 0` and toggled `isItemsFixed` when we call `prepareNextItemsToLoad()`.

One more thing to take note, `LoadoutItemIterator.next()` should throw [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) when your `Location`s are fully exhausted, which you can also determine by comparing `currentLocation`. In full:

```
@Override
public T next() {
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T ans = nextItem();
    index++;
    return ans;
}
```

I have taken a final liberty to rename `getNextNonFiltered` as `nextItem`, because personally for me, seeing a method with a `get` prefix inside anything remotely `Iterable` sounds like we have already moved on and incremented our index when the method returns. This could be just me though.

**One more edit**

D'oh, now that I have completed my review, I also realized my uses of `isItemsFixed` are already encapsulated within methods... So feel free to stick with your `IterationState` `enum`, and replace the `boolean` comparisons with the appropriate `if ( state == IterationState.Fixed )...` clauses. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's too long for the time I can spend now, so just some random comments:

Assuming `Location` is an `enum`, you can replace

```
private final static Location[] LOCATION_ORDER;
LOCATION_ORDER = new Location[Location.values().length];
for(Location location : Location.values()){
    LOCATION_ORDER[location.ordinal()] = location;
}
```

by

```
private final static Location[] LOCATION_ORDER = Location.values();
```

---

> How can I (if I can) get rid of the unchecked cast?

This is strange:

```
if( filter == null || filter.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass()) ){
    return (T)item; // This cast is checked
}
```

Firstly, I'd replace `null` by `Object.class` for `filter`. You want everything and everything is an Object. Secondly, the condition can be expressed simpler. Thirdly, there is `Class#cast`.

```
if (filter.isInstance(item) return filter.cast(item);
```

But even this sounds too complicated, given that there's Guava's [`Iterables#filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class)) doing exactly this.

---

I can't see how `getNextNonFiltered` can be non-filtered when it uses `filter`.

---

Consider implementing `Location#next()` to move the functionality to where it belongs.

---

I don't understand the loop, so I can't tell more. Consider using [`AbstractIterator`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.html) or extracting methods to make it clearer.

Comment: I did some benchmarking and having the null check is faster for the non-filter case. As this kind of iteration is done quite frequently I will prefer the null check on performance grounds. But otherwise I agree.

Comment: @EmilyL. Then you can't get rid of the unchecked cast. But you can place `@SuppressWarnings` on a local variable and so limit its scope.

Comment: In order to add a `next()` I would need a `first()` and `hasNext()` and in that case I might as well use an `Iterator` to `Arrays.asList(Location.values())`. I do not have Guava as a dependency and I'm trying to keep my jar size down for (near) future android port.